# view more button is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

In my posts I am trying to add a gallery of images. I want to have a load more button show up after 4 images. Then you would press the load more button and 4 more appear, and so on. I have created the html, css, and js, but for some reason it is not working.  Can anyone help me find a solution? Thanks in advance. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8zfz6hap/

html

```html
<div class="shop-gallery">  
<div class="product"> 
<a href="#" target="_blank">
<img src='http://nord.imgix.net/Zoom/19/_12156979.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFF&fm=jpg&q=60&w=380&h=583'>
</a>
</div> <div class="product"> 
<a href="#" target="_blank">
<img src='http://nord.imgix.net/Zoom/19/_12156979.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFF&fm=jpg&q=60&w=380&h=583'>
</a>
</div> <div class="product"> 
<a href="href="#" target="_blank">
<img src='http://nord.imgix.net/Zoom/19/_12156979.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFF&fm=jpg&q=60&w=380&h=583'>
</a>
</div> <div class="product"> 
<a href="#" target="_blank">
<img src='http://nord.imgix.net/Zoom/19/_12156979.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFF&fm=jpg&q=60&w=380&h=583'>
</a>
</div> <div class="product"> 
<a href="#" target="_blank">
<img src='http://nord.imgix.net/Zoom/19/_12156979.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFF&fm=jpg&q=60&w=380&h=583'>
</a>
</div> <div class="product"> 
<a href="href="#" target="_blank">
<img src='http://nord.imgix.net/Zoom/19/_12156979.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFF&fm=jpg&q=60&w=380&h=583'>
</a>
</div> <div class='product'> 
<a href="#" target="_blank">
<img src='http://nord.imgix.net/Zoom/19/_12156979.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFF&fm=jpg&q=60&w=380&h=583'>
</a>
</div> <div class='product'> 
<a href="#" target="_blank">
<img src='http://nord.imgix.net/Zoom/19/_12156979.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFF&fm=jpg&q=60&w=380&h=583'>
</a>
</div> 
</div>
<button id="load-more-comments">Load More</button>
```

js

```html
var $parent = $("#shop-gallery"),
    $items = $parent.find("#product"),
    $loadMoreBtn = $("#load-more-comments"),
    maxItems = 4,
    hiddenClass = "visually-hidden";

  // add visually hidden class to items beyond maxItems
  $.each($items, function(idx,item){
      if(idx > maxItems - 1){
        $(this).addClass(hiddenClass);
      }
    });

  // onclick of show more button show more = maxItems
  // if there are none left to show kill show more button
  $loadMoreBtn.on("click", function(e){
      $("."+hiddenClass).each(function(idx,item){
        if(idx < maxItems - 1){
          $(this).removeClass(hiddenClass);
        }
        // kill button if no more to show
        if($("."+hiddenClass).size() === 0){
          $loadMoreBtn.hide();
        }
      });
    });
```

css

```html
.product img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: calc(100% - 48px);
    max-height: calc(100% - 48px);

}
.product {
    width: 21%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 3.5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.visually-hidden { 
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  height: 1px; width: 1px; 
  margin: -1px; padding: 0; border: 0; 
}
```

Comment: can you shrink your code? it's not the easiest to read currently. Try taking out bits that don't effect this view more button

Comment: You probably really want to cache all the images first, since you would not be using the same image. If you make sure all of your images end with a number, the first being 0, you can easily dynamically add them, creating Elements as needed. Just a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**shop-gallery** and **product** both are classes.

Need to use :

```
var $parent = $(".shop-gallery"),
    $items = $parent.find(".product")
```

To select and actions on them. `.` instead of `#`

Example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5sxtxqkc/3/)

**Update**:

In order to hide load more button use condition - `$("." + hiddenClass).length === 0` and to show 4 images, your code is correct just update the condition to `idx < maxItems` so that it true for idx - 0,1,2,3 which will be four images.

Example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5sxtxqkc/4/)

Comment: Thank you! However now it is only loading 1 item at a time, and I want it to load 4 at a time. Also the load more button isn't going away if all items are loaded. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: @user6738171 : Updated the answer.  :)

Comment: Thank you so much! One more problem I just noticed - the code only seems to be working in that one example fiddle you posted? I tried using it in wordpress and it didn't work, so I went back and tried pasting the code into a new fiddle, and even a code pen and they both didn't work. They both produce this - https://jsfiddle.net/9ub6jo6e/

Comment: Did you include jQuery? In the fiddle I have created click on the JavaScript tag and you will see I have included jQuery.

Comment: Yes it did, can't believe I missed that! Thank you so much!